# Numbers are printed too far down

Tags: c, printing

i want to print the square numbers next to the numbers from 1 - 10.
I used \t but it looks like \t\v.

```
printf("n \t\t n*n \t\t s(n) \t\t q(n)");
printf("\n");
int i;
i = 0;

while(i<=10)
{
printf("%d\n",i);
i++;
}

for(i=1; i<=10;i++)
{
printf("\n\t\t%d", i*i);
}
```

Can't find a solution and i just started coding in C last week.

```
n        n*n         s(n)        q(n)
1
2
3        
4        1
5        4
6        9
7        16
8        25
9        36
10       49
         64
         81
         100
```

Comment: Please post your code as text included directly in the post; images of code don't work very well here.

Comment: Also, if possible, please provide a [mre], which is a full (but minimal) program, including a function `main` and all `#include` directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's logically follow the code you have provided.

```
printf("n \t\t n*n \t\t s(n) \t\t q(n)");
printf("\n");
```

Will print

```
n                n*n             s(n)            q(n)
```

Now, after the first while loop you will print each number from `i` to `i=10` in a new line, leading to:

```
0
1
2
...
10
```

This makes sense. Lastly, you are using another for loop with another `printf()` call to print `n*n`, again, in a new line for each entry.

```
            1
            4
            9
            ...
            100
```

You have to notice that `printf()` will always print ONE line and as soon as you are jumping to the next line with `\n` there is no way of going back to the previously printed line (at least when printing to the console).

The easiest fix would be to only use one for loop that prints and calculates all of the necessary values for a specific `i`. The print statement could look similar to:

```
printf("%d \t\t %d \t\t %d \t\t %d", value1, value2, value3, value4);
```

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"there is no way of going back to the previously printed line`" -- Actually, that is not quite correct. Since OP seems to be on the Microsoft Windows platform, they could use [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) to jump around on the screen, or they could [use console virtual terminal sequences to jump around](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-positioning). However, you are right that this is not possible in pure ISO C.

Comment: Thank you very much and very well explained for a beginner like me. Can't imagine how long i was stuck at this. And sorry for the format of my question it was my first try here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
   printf("%d\t%d\n",i,i*i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of providing a code-only answer, you may also want to explain in a few words what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: I have just provided the same answer with a little more explanation. @AbhishekHarsh, especially when people to seem be new to a certain language, more explanation might help them understand better!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
printf("n \t\t n*n \t\t s(n) \t\t q(n)");
printf("\n");
int i;
i = 0;

while(i<=10)
{
    printf("%d \t\t %d \n",i,i*i);
    i++;
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

I hope this would be helpful to you..

Comment: Instead of providing a code-only answer, you may also want to explain in a few words what was wrong and how you fixed it.